# usercontrol vs iframe, limitations and known problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, user-controls

If this is too hypothetical and needs to be somewhere else, please let me know.

I have a project that needs specific `gridviews` to appear on multiple pages. Instead of copying and pasting the `gridviews` on each of the pages I thought creating a `user control` for each specific `gridview` or create a page for each `gridview` and then use `iframes` would be my best options.

I have not used either extensively so I am looking to the SO community's experience, are there known problems with using `user controls` and/or `iframes` when it comes to:

1. validation
2. communication between `user control`/`iframe` and parent page
3. `ajax`/`updatepanels` containing `user control`/`iframe`

thanks in advance

Comment: `iframes` are generally looked down upon. They complicate things.

Comment: User controls on the other hand are not, and are likely just what you want to be working with.

Answer (score 0):

Since a gridview is essentially a user control (that's very flexible), I would first explore doing this with neither of your options. If possible, use the standard gridview and let your data layer do most the work. However, assuming you already know that... but your requirements require one or the other of your options, here are things to consider.

An iframe is easy to implement but unless your need is really simplistic in terms of user interaction, the user control will be the most flexible. Another downside to an iframe is it's size (you're essentially loading two pages). The downside of user controls are the upfront time in building them.

Based on your criterion:

**1. validation** - can do with either option but you'll have more flexibility with a user control

**2. communication between user control/iframe and parent page** - much easier with user control unless query string parms will do the trick

**3. ajax/updatepanels containing user control/iframe** - again user control